# What about creating a tag "wind-instruments"?

Tags: discussion

Currently existing are tags "woodwinds" (also woodwind-instruments) and "brass". I'd like to introduce the general "wind" or "wind-instruments" for these reasons:

- summarize these two (so they don't need to be added separately)
- have a possibility to specify problems not specific to any of the detailed ones (e.g. breathing technique)
- symmetry reasons compared to "strings" of similar generality

Disadvantages:

- not orthogonal to the tags mentioned
- intersection with "breathing"

Comment: I only see 4 questions tagged `[woodwinds][brass]`, so it doesn't seem like we need this.  Tags should be created for current use, rather than future potentials -- and it seems like things like breathing technique are already better suited to being tagged with `[technique][breathing]` as many already are.